# Conventional way to resolve docker derived image build time vs. image size tradeoff

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Two constraints are often important in writing Dockerfiles: image size and image build time.

It's a commonplace observation that time and space usage can often be traded off for one another.  However, it can be useful to avoid that choice by going for fast build time in development and small-but-slower builds in production.

For example, if I write something like this in a project I can quickly rebuild the images in development when `frequently_changing_source_code` changes, because there is a layer with `build-essential` installed that can be reused in the derived image:

base image:

```
RUN apt install build-essential python-dev && \
 pip install some-pypi-project
ADD frequently_changing_source_code
```

derived image:

```
FROM base_image
RUN pip install another-pypi-project-requiring-build-essential
ADD more_stuff
```

The above results in larger builds than this next version, which achieves the same functionality but sacrifices build times. Now whenever `frequently_changing_source_code` changes, rebuilding the derived image results in a re-install of `build-essential`:

base image:

```
RUN apt install build-essential python-dev && \
 pip install some-pypi-project && \
 apt remove build-essential python-dev
ADD frequently_changing_source_code
```

derived image:

```
FROM base_image
RUN apt install build-essential python-dev && \
 pip install another-pypi-project-requiring-build-essential && \
 apt remove build-essential python-dev
ADD more_stuff
```

I can imagine ways of solving this: for example, writing a slightly more complicated set of Dockerfiles that are parameterized on some sort of development flag, which has the first behaviour for development builds, and the second for production builds.  I suspect that would not result in Dockerfiles that people like to read and use, though.

**So**, how can I best achieve my ends **without surprising other developers**: i.e. using Dockerfiles that respect docker conventions as much as I can?

Some notes about answers I've considered:

I'm aware of the layer-caching behaviour of docker (that is why the ADD commands for both images in my example are at the end).

I'm aware that one can mount code using -v.  Using -v is my usual practice, but this question is about building images, which is also something that happens in development (from time to time, it happens quite a lot).

One obvious suggestion is to eliminate the base image.  However, note that for the projects concerned, the base image is typically a base for multiple images, so merging the base with those would result in a bunch of repeated directives in each of those Dockerfiles.  Perhaps this is the least-worst option, though.

Also note that (again, in the projects I'm involved with) the mere presence of the `frequently_changing_source_code` does not by itself significantly contribute to build times: it is re-installs of packages like build-essential that does that.  `another-pypi-project-requiring-build-essential` typically does contribute significantly to build times, but perhaps not enough to need to eliminate that step in development builds too.

Finally, though it is a commonly-cited nice feature of docker that it's possible to use the same configuration in development as in production, this particular source of variation is not a significant concern for us.

Comment: Seems relevant: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3378

Answer (score 1):

In the past there hasn't really been a good answer to this. You either build two different images, one for fast moving developers and the other for compact distribution, or you pick one that's less than ideal for others. There's a potential workaround if the developers compile the code themselves and simply mount their compiled product directly into the container as a volume for testing without a rebuild.

But last week docker added the ability to have a multi-stage build in 17.05.0-ce-rc1 (see [pr 32063](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/32063)). They allow you to build parts of the app in separate pieces and copy the results into another image at the end, with caching of all the layers while the final image only contains the layers of the last section of the build. So for your scenario, you could have something like:

```
FROM debian:latest as build-env
# you can split these run lines now since these layers are only used at build
RUN apt install build-essential python-dev
RUN pip install some-pypi-project
RUN pip install another-pypi-project-requiring-build-essential
# you only need this next remove if the build tools are in the same folders as the app
RUN apt remove build-essential python-dev

FROM debian:latest
# update this copy command depending on the pip install location
COPY --from=build-env /usr/bin /usr/bin
ADD frequently_changing_source_code
ADD more_stuff
```

All the layers in the first build environment stick around in the cache, letting developers add and remove as they need to, without having to rerun the build-essential install. But in the final image, there's just 3 layers added, one copy command from the build-env and a couple adds, resulting in a small image. And if they only change files in those `ADD` commands, then only those steps run.

Here's an [early blog post](http://blog.alexellis.io/mutli-stage-docker-builds/) going into it in more detail. This is now available as an RC and you can expect it in the 17.05 edge release from docker, hopefully in the next few weeks. If you want to see another example of this really put to use, have a look at the [miragesdk Dockerfile](https://github.com/linuxkit/linuxkit/blob/94583013aa0533e1574e21157ce20e67cfdfba3f/projects/miragesdk/src/Dockerfile).

Comment: I will try to clarify in the question but: Option 1: We already do this, as shown in the question? (within a *single* image) The question is about multiple images. Towards the end points out the motivation for the use of derivation feature. Option 2: Sure, this is my usual way of working. But it's not so rare that one wants to build images a lot when developing (e.g. when debugging CI failures, or changing rarely-modified files, or otherwise to avoid opportunity for introducing errors in manually mapping source tree paths to image paths). Building images is what I'm asking about here.

Comment: Option 3: interesting!  I'll have to study that to understand how/whether relevant to what I'm getting at.  Maybe split answer or remove options 1/2?

Comment: While option 3 may be right for you, the others may help someone else coming across this question later, so I hesitate to remove them. Splitting feels a bit like rep begging to me (SO doesn't let me say the word I was really thinking of), but if others feel that's better, I can do that.

Comment: Others may find them useful, but they are answers to questions I was not trying to ask.  I do think it's quite central to SO to keep questions focused.  I've edited the question to try and make it clearer, but if I failed please suggest or make edits.

Comment: You're right, I see where the wording was that confused me, entirely my fault for skimming too fast. Let me think about how to reword this to make it a better answer that focuses directly on your question.

Comment: This is a great answer. I'm not sure it fits my problem. Even if it doesn't I'm tempted to change the question to match the answer :-)  I'll experiment with this next week...